# Error when trying to integrate the Linkedin SDK into my Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, podfile, objc-bridging-header

I am trying to integrate the Linkedin SDK into my Swift project. I am using [this cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/LinkedinSwift) and this is the error I'm getting.

Use of unresolved identifier 'LinkedinSwiftHelper'

**My podfile:**

use_frameworks!

target 'JobRewards' do
pod 'LinkedinSwift', '~> 1.6.5'

end

**This is the line where I am getting the error, I am declaring this right after the class declaration of my View Controller:**

```
let linkedinHelper = LinkedinSwiftHelper(configuration: LinkedinSwiftConfiguration(clientId: "myclientid", clientSecret: "myclientsecret", state: "mystate", permissions: ["r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress"]))
```

**My bridging header:**

```
#ifndef ObjectiveCHeader_h
#define ObjectiveCHeader_h

#import <LinkedinSwift/LSHeader.h> // this will use both for POD and import framework.


#endif /* ObjectiveCHeader_h */
```

**My info.plist source code:**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>linkedin.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LIAppId</key>
<string>4594413</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>li4594413</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>linkedin</string>
    <string>linkedin-sdk2</string>
    <string>linkedin-sdk</string>
</array>
```

On build settings/Objective-C bridging header this is the current path:

```
/Users/myName/Desktop/PROJECTS/MyProject/MyProject/ObjectiveCHeader.h
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I have been struggling with this for 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the bridging header when using cocoa pods. Are you importing LinkedInSwift in the Swift file that includes that viewcontroller? For me, this compiled with no issues.

```
import UIKit
import LinkedinSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let linkedinHelper = LinkedinSwiftHelper()

}
```

Comment: No problem. You might want to remove that bridging header if its the only thing you were using it for.